# How to clip path the SVG under the Circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a HTML Document with Javascript. It's a Circle Animation on Page ScrollY which fit the viewport width.

Currently the circle working perfectly, but i want a SVG to clip the circle. So when it will scroll down the XG Svg will be animate and fit to the viewport width.

https://codepen.io/sashikanta/pen/KKqPqoq

```
<svg id="Layer_1" class="svg_clip" width="200" height="200" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 554.41 358.76"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#b3b3b3;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M401.64,164.38c-6.25,13-5.08,28.09-13.94,40.8-9.2,13.16-18.28,26.48-27.76,39.47-5,6.91-11.43,12.93-17.45,19.12s-10.53,6.41-16.27.22c-11.32-12.21-22.24-24.75-33.45-37-3.51-3.85-4.23-7.75-1.84-12.27,2.07-4,3.68-8.24,6.3-11.81,8.08-11.15,13.88-22.86,11.82-37.24-.78-5.24,3-6.41,7.3-6.41,13.55-.05,27.09,0,40.64,0,12.87,0,25.81-.05,38.68,0C399,159.31,403.42,160.65,401.64,164.38Z" transform="translate(-142.59 -152.72)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M697,388.72c0,42.59-8,122.76-129.77,122.76-56.15,0-109.3-11.61-124.8-68.66a11.48,11.48,0,0,1,11-14.52h62.36a11.18,11.18,0,0,1,10.66,7.37c2.48,7.27,6.56,12.11,12.7,15.18,7.51,4,18,5.51,31.07,5.51,40.58,0,44.59-28.56,44.59-60.63V371.18h-1a82.35,82.35,0,0,1-69.15,38.08C466,409.26,430.44,353.14,430.44,280c0-69.15,40.58-127.27,114.24-127.27,31.07,0,54.61,13.53,69.65,40.08h1V171.65a11.41,11.41,0,0,1,11.41-11.42h58.85A11.41,11.41,0,0,1,697,171.65ZM565.22,217.86c-37.57,0-49.6,33.07-49.6,65.13,0,30.57,14,61.13,49.1,61.13,36.08,0,51.61-28.05,51.61-60.63C616.33,250.43,603.31,217.86,565.22,217.86Z" transform="translate(-142.59 -152.72)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M187.18,158.92h36.91c4.47,0,6.75,1.72,7.51,6.67,4.41,28.94,19.09,52.67,38.75,73.59,24.77,26.36,50,52.26,74.59,78.8,19.22,20.78,37.85,42.16,48.89,68.78,2.17,5.25,4.31,10.87,4.69,16.44,1.37,20.56-.25,16.78-16.15,16.86-20.07.11-40.15-.07-60.22.1-6,.06-8.89-1.22-10-8.24-4.28-26.74-18.07-48.88-35.49-69.05-3.11-3.59-5.25-4.52-9-.46-17.85,19.17-30.24,41.15-35.93,66.83-2.37,10.67-2.47,10.78-13.06,10.83-21.37.09-42.74.2-64.11-.05-10.36-.13-10.57-1.34-9.68-12.29,1.85-23,14.82-40.91,27.36-58.56,9.65-13.58,21.87-25.35,33.16-37.73,6.54-7.17,13.5-13.95,20.27-20.9-6.2-7.07-12.51-14.06-18.57-21.24-13.69-16.21-27.75-32.13-40.73-48.89C154,204.5,147.12,186,142.91,166.27c-1.24-5.8,1.21-7.13,5.42-7.21,12.95-.25,25.9-.09,38.85-.09Z" transform="translate(-142.59 -152.72)"/></svg>
```

I have tried something like this

```
section
    {
     position: fixed;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100vh;
     background: url(background.jpg);
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
    /*clip-path: circle(100px at center); */
     clip-path: url(#Layer_1);
    }
```

Comment: Layer_1 is not a clipPath element it's an svg element. The clip-path CSS property must reference a clipPath element if you want it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment, Then how to Animate ?

Comment: With [SMIL perhaps](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SMIL_animations)